# Why is the diffraction pattern for an annular aperture the difference of the two Bessel functions?

Tags: optics, diffraction

Inspired by [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18390/focusing-laser-off-axis-illumination-diffraction-limit), the pattern for the annular intensity is given by the square of the difference of the two Bessel functions.  I would have thought the sum was more appropriate, could someone explain why not?

Comment: Because you can think of it as two circular apertures, the middle one being a "negative" aperture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Genneth above:

The equation given represents the electric field at the image surface, by superposition this is the sum of the two apertures, one term positive and one negative.