# Resolving power of ultra-telescopes

Tags: optics, astronomy, telescopes

Assuming we could create and orbit optical telescopes of arbitrary size, perhaps starting with (say) inflatables or [active membrane](http://web.stanford.edu/~gorin/papers/SPIE_AstroPreprint_02.pdf) of 100m diameter what kind of resolution in imaging extra-solar planets would we get? Then the same question for increasing orders of magnitude up to 100km diameter. Any theoretical reason why something that large could not be made?

Comment: Closely related (if not a duplicate): http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17881/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The angular resolution of a telescope is given approximately by $1.22 \lambda/D$ in radians, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of observation and $D$ is the diameter of a circular mirror.

Say we study a star that is 10pc away with a telescope working in the optical band (you didn't specify) at 500nm, then the *spatial* resolution of a 100m telescope at the distance of the star will be 0.012 AU= 1.9 million km! Much less than the orbit of Mercury.

This should solve one of the great problems in exoplanet astronomy. We cannot see planets around other stars, not because of a lack of sensitivity (even now), but because of the contrast problem with the parent star. Even light beyond the first minimum of the Airy disc can cause problems, but with a formal resolution of 0.012 AU, a planet at 1 AU even, if many orders of magnitude fainter than the star, should be observable, but not itself resolved. The only imaged exoplanets at present are a few things with masses of $\sim10$ Jupiter masses situated tens of au from their parent stars.

To resolve the surface of the exoplanet, you need to make a bigger telescope. The spatial resolution will increase linearly with the telecope diameter. So a resolution of 1000km, will need a telescope (for a star at 10pc) about 2000 times bigger - i.e. a diameter of 200km.

There would of course be massive practical difficulties in engineering a surface of that size held precisely in position with an accuracy of better than about 30nm. I suspect it far more likely that future ultra-telescopes will consist of interferometric arrays that have very large baselines, perhaps even larger than 200km, but consist of individually much smaller telescopes. A planet like Jupiter *could* be detected by a $\sim 5$m diameter space telescope (i.e. there are enough photons), but without the angular resolution afforded by an array, its light would be lost against the glare of its parent star.

EDIT: A nice paper (thanks @Warrick) that discusses the concepts of using large arrays in the optical (it is of course well established at radio and mm wavelengths), *specifically* to resolve exoplanets is given by [Labeyrie et al. (1996)](http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs/1996A%26AS..118..517L). A more recent paper: ["Resolved Imaging of Extra-Solar Photosynthesis Patches with a ``Laser Driven Hypertelescope Flotilla"](http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs/2010ASPC..430..239L) looks even more exciting!

Comment: You point out the very practical problem that the surface of your telescope needs to be shaped to within a fraction of a wavelength of the ideal shape for any of this to matter. Luckily with no gravity you might just be able to do it with a very, very large soap bubble that has a (tiny) differential pressure applied across it. Now that would be an AWESOME experiment. Just hope that it doesn't go "pop" at the wrong time. Astronauts blowing soap bubbles - I can't see it taking off.

Comment: @Floris "No gravity"? Unfortunately a 200km mirror will be subject to tides!

Comment: Rob - I'm thinking "far out into space" not in some pesky near earth orbit. You wanna see big, you gotta thing big.

Comment: @Floris I do think that big will mean a big array. I believe the technological challenges are fewer, plus if one thing goes wrong it doesn't necessarily destroy the whole experiment.

Comment: @RobJeffries: the idea of an interferometric array is the idea behind [Antoine Labeyrie's "hypertelescope"](https://lise.oca.eu/spip.php?rubrique74), which occasionally gets coverage.

Comment: Wait, I thought we already had directly imaged exoplanets, as mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_directly_imaged_exoplanets) and shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_detecting_exoplanets#Direct_imaging).

Comment: @honeste_vivere A handful of giant "planets" (they could yet be brown dwarfs) have been resolved at large distances (tens of au) from their parent star. No exoplanet surfaces have been resolved of course.