# Is there a limit to telescope resolution?

Tags: optics, telescopes

Could a strong enough telescope read a newspaper on a planet 1400 light years away, or is there a theoretical limit to the resolution of magnification?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a limit to the resolving power of a mirror telescope?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17881/)

Comment: For a distance of 1400 ly, you would need a telescope of diameter (or at least separation between furthest components) of 1 ly in order to resolve 1 mm print in visible light. It's not clear that building a telescope of size 1 ly is any more difficult than traveling 1400 ly and just asking for a copy of the 452b Gazette.