# What are the observable emissions from an ion engine? What percent of input power ends up as heat, UV, or other emissions?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, plasma-physics

I'm wondering what would be observable to an astronomer if one knew where to look for a distant space craft with a powerful ion engine such as a Dual-Stage 4-Grid (DS4G) electrostatic thruster. In the near future I suspect these to be used by drones and probes and I wonder if you'd need an observatory or just a nice telescope to see them.

I've searched high and low for what kind of light comes out of an ion engine and how safe the plume is, and found only [a single post from a then PhD student working on electrode erosion](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/5491xz/is_the_exhaust_from_an_ion_thruster_hot_reactive/).

Comment: You might be able to get an answer to this question on [Space.SE] instead of here.

Comment: The Meta post literally stipulates resolving things in a telescope as an example of what is allowed. Maybe we need another metapost about drive-by moderators endlessly punting things? Why would emissions from a plasma not be physics?

Comment: Are any engineering questions allowed? Questions inspired by engineering considerations can be on-topic on this site. For instance, it would be valid to ask if there is a fundamental physical limit to --How well one could resolve an object with a telescope--

Comment: I didn't vote to close (and the people who did are community members, not moderators) but [the question about the fundamental physical limits of a telescope has been asked and answered.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17881/is-there-a-limit-to-the-resolving-power-of-a-mirror-telescope)

Comment: Yes, which is which is why you need to know the emissions of what you're looking at, which is what I'm asking about.

Comment: "I've searched high and low..." Did you look at the articles linked on the Wikipedia site for "Dual-Stage 4-Grid?" Like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-Stage_4-Grid#cite_note-esapaper-3

Comment: (+1) I can’t answer your question, which is good, but I can say that the exhaust xenon from the ion engine will emit light at xenon’s characteristic atomic emission wavelengths, like shown in the last photo (the plasma globe 2D spectrum) here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49116/45954. If you wish, can temporarily post a 2D spectrum (echellogram) of a xenon discharge tube and put the link in another comment. My gut feeling is that astronomers could very probably see the xenon lines using their exoplanet-hunting echelle spectrographs and large telescopes.